# Adding enum values?

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement

Can I create an enum (constants to use in a switch statement) from two enums???

Something like...

```
public class Test{

    public enum WorkDay {Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday,Friday};
    public enum WeekEndDay {Sunday, Saturday};

    // it doesn't work ):
    public enum Day{WorkDay.values(),WeekEndDay.values()}; 

    public static void Action(Day d) {

        switch(d){
            case Monday:
                ...;
                break;
            case Tuesday:
                ...;
                break;
            case ...:
                ...;
                break;
            case Saturday:
                ...;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea??? I really want to use *switch* and have separated the enums
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. You could create a `Day` enum and *explicitly* list each value, providing a constructor for each type as well... but personally I'd use:

```
public enum Day {
    MONDAY(true),
    TUESDAY(true),
    WEDNESDAY(true),
    THURSDAY(true),
    FRIDAY(true),
    SATURDAY(false),
    SUNDAY(false);

    private final boolean workDay;

    private Day(boolean workDay) {
        this.workDay = workDay;
    }

    public boolean isWorkDay() {
        return workDay;
    }
}
```

You could then *also* publish an `EnumSet<Day>` for work days and another for non-work days.

Comment: Didn't know about EnumSet. Learning something every day.

Answer (score 0):

You can't combine Enums since WorkDay, WeekEndDay and Day are all different classes.
The best you can do is:

```
public enum Day {
    Monday(false),
    Tuesday(false),
    Wednesday(false),
    Thursday(false),
    Friday(false),
    Saturday(true),
    Sunday(true);
    private boolean isWeekendDay;
    private Day(boolean isWeekendDay) {
        this.isWeekendDay = isWeekendDay;
    }
    public boolean isWeekendDay() {
        return isWeekendDay;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Effective Java has a very good example for enum that can fit your requirement. The author suggests to you the strategy pattern. The code can be like:

```
// The strategy enum pattern
enum SomeActionDay {
    MONDAY(DayActionType.WEEKDAY), TUESDAY(DayActionType.WEEKDAY),
    WEDNESDAY(DayActionType.WEEKDAY), THURSDAY(DayActionType.WEEKDAY),
    FRIDAY(DayActionType.WEEKDAY),
    SATURDAY(DayActionType.WEEKEND), SUNDAY(DayActionType.WEEKEND);
private final DayActionType dayType;
SomeActionDay(DayActionType dayType) { this.dayType = dayType; }
return-type takeAction(parameters) {
    return dayType.takeAction(parameters);
}
// The strategy enum type
private enum DayActionType {
WEEKDAY {
return action(parameters) {
//business logic for weekday. return value
}
},
WEEKEND {
return action(parameters) {
//business logic for weekday. return value
}
};

abstract returntype action(parameters);

}
}
```